# Custom Toolbar getting view covered

Tags: android

I have the flowing toolbar

toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark">
```

and im calling it in main activity:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

here is the problem:

[image]

toolbar/actionbar covering my main activity.

> how can i fix this without the use of padding? prefer it to be in java code.

btw im using `LayoutInflator` and my main activity `extends ActionBarActivity` to use with Navigation Drawer.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_load_game, null, false);
    dr.addView(contentView,1)
```

Tell me if you need more information, or i missed something.

Thanks

Comment: `Toolbar` now acts like an UI component in a view hierarchy instead of part of an Activity's window decor controlled by Android framework; so you may need to lay it out like other UI components...either by padding it or use relative layout positioning. With AppCompat v7 release 22+, you may need to use it with `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` theme.